# Как загрузить скетч с одного Arduino на другой?

Tags: c++, arduino

Есть две Arduino Mega 2560. Как можно загрузить скетч на одну из Arduino, используя USB кабель, ПК и другую Arduino?

На одну из Arduino не загружаются скетчи с ПК, однако с ней можно взаимодействовать из другой Arduino (подать сигнал, замигать лампочкой). Но конкретно нужно загрузить программу на вторую Arduino. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключить вторую по ICSP, в первую Arduino загрузить скетч [Arduino as ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) и прошить bootloader для Mega во вторую. После этого вторую можно будет подключать по USB-кабелю так же, как обычный Arduino.